# Why are my GlobalStyles not working after deploying with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, github-pages, styled-components

I'm using React, Redux, styled components and GitHub pages with my app.

Global styles work in development, but do not get applied after deploying to GitHub pages.

e.g. in App.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
   body {
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand");
      color: red;
   }
`

const App = () => (
   <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Router>
            <div>
              //REST OF APP
            </div>
         </Router>
      </Provider>
   </React.Fragment>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Does it work if you run a production build locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that there is currently an issue when using `@import` in Global Styles. The solution is to take the `@import` out and place it elsewhere, such as in a link tag, if you're using Google fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is unclear when it comes to using @import within createGlobalStyle. There seems to a be a difference in production compared to development, most likely to stop FOUC, if you move the @import into the top-level then it will import correctly and display your styles.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
   @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand");
   body {
      color: red;
   }
`

const App = () => (
   <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Router>
            <div>
              //REST OF APP
            </div>
         </Router>
      </Provider>
   </>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too and your info about the issue helped me. Thanks @Brendan!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 1):

your request to https is blocked once you upload it to GitHub pages, so your css import fails

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I went to deploy my React app's production build that uses Google fonts. Then I discovered this awesome project: https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces. It has *all* of the Google fonts, and makes them available via NPM.

Essentially, all I had to do was

```
npm install typeface-pt-mono --save
```

Then in the top-level `index.js` that renders my `App.js` component:

```
import "typeface-pt-mono";
```

That's it. Now everywhere in my app that I have css that refers to 
`font-family: "PT Mono"` it just works.